# Hash#compare_by_identity with string literals

Tags: ruby, string, hash, string-comparison

I'm running Ruby 2.2.1.
The following code runs as expected as string hash keys are duped and frozen:

```
f = 'foo'              
h = {f => 'bar'}       
h.compare_by_identity  
h[f]                  # => nil 
h['foo']              # => nil 
h[h.keys.first]       # => "bar"
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on here:

```
h = {'foo' => 'bar'}   
h.compare_by_identity  
h.keys.first.frozen?   # => true 
'foo'.frozen?          # => false 
h.keys.first.object_id # => 20421220 
'foo'.object_id        # => 20067280 
h['foo']               # => "bar" 
h['foo'.dup]           # => nil
```

It's interesting to note the the docs for #compare_by_identity started using #dup at 2.2.0. So it seems this behavior change is known.

2.1.7:

```
h1["a"]        #=> nil  # different objects.
```

2.2.0:

```
h1["a".dup]    #=> nil  # different objects.
```

However, the source is the same.

The same does not happen with other literals like arrays. Any ideas on why this behavior changed for string literals? The docs give no hints as to why.

Comment: `"a"` and `"a".dup` necessarily have different `object_id`'s, no? (I'm wondering if I'm missing some nuance in your question here.) Without `compare_by_identity`, `h['foo'] == h['foo'.dup]`.

Comment: To your question, yes. But every string literal also has a different `object_id`. E.g.,

`'foo'.object_id # => 6989460 `
`'foo'.object_id # => 6973080`
`

Comment: I suppose `Hash` is telling us it doesn't care for purposes of key lookup (since `"a" == "a".dup`), unless we tell it to.

Comment: But after we tell it to, it still treats string literals as matching.
But maybe you are on the right track. Since a string literal can never have the same `object_id` as whatever was previously stored, Ruby might be deciding to ignore the `compare_by_identity` for them.
That still seems very astonishing since you have to explicitly tell it to `compare_by_identity`, only for it to sneakily ignore it for string literals.